# Minimize my code and avoid repetitions vba

Tags: vba, loops, repeat

can you help me to minimise this code. I need to count everey condtionnel cell colors for several ranges.

I buit this code for  the first range rng1 and should do the same for all 7 ranges:

```
Public Sub CountColorCells()
    'Variable declaration
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim rng3 As Range
    Dim rng4 As Range
    Dim rng5 As Range
    Dim rng6 As Range
    Dim rng7 As Range
          
    Dim Cnter1 As Long
    Dim Cnter2 As Long
    Dim Cnter3 As Long
    Dim Cnter4 As Long
     
    Dim rngCell As Range
       
    'Set the range
    Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("statut projet et Gate").Range("M8:M1000")
    Set rng2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("statut projet et Gate").Range("Q8:Q1000")
    Set rng3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("statut projet et Gate").Range("U8:U1000")
    Set rng4 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("statut projet et Gate").Range("Y8:Y1000")
    Set rng5 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("statut projet et Gate").Range("AC8:AC1000")
    Set rng6 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("statut projet et Gate").Range("AG8:AG1000")
    Set rng7 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("statut projet et Gate").Range("AK8:AK1000")
    
 
    'loop throught each cell in the range
    For Each rngCell In rng1
      
       Select Case Cells(rngCell.Row, rngCell.Column).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
       
         Case RGB(146, 208, 80)
             Cnter1 = Cnter1 + 1
             ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("statut projet et Gate").Range("M2") = Cnter1
                    
         Case RGB(255, 255, 0)
             Cnter2 = Cnter2 + 1
             ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("statut projet et Gate").Range("M3") = Cnter2
                  
         Case RGB(255, 0, 0)
             Cnter3 = Cnter3 + 1
             ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("statut projet et Gate").Range("M4") = Cnter3
                  
         Case RGB(0, 176, 240)
             Cnter4 = Cnter4 + 1
             ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("statut projet et Gate").Range("M5") = Cnter4
            
            
        
        End Select
        
      
     Next
   
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility: Just use `Union` to combine all the ranges into one:

```
Dim rng As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("statut projet et Gate")
    Set rng = Union(.Range("M8:M1000"), _
                    .Range("Q8:Q1000"), _
                    .Range("U8:U1000"), _
                    .Range("Y8:Y1000"), _
                    .Range("AC8:AC1000"), _
                    .Range("AG8:AG1000"), _
                    .Range("AK8:AK1000"))
End With
    
For Each rngCell In rng
   (...)
Next
```

Attention: You are talking about *conditionnel cell colors*. If cells are colored using Conditional Formatting, you need to check `rngCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`

Comment: Thank for your response, really appreciated. But in this casse of union, how the counter will be a specific for each range in union, I tested but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fewer variables, and loop over the ranges to be counted, since they have a regular offset:

```vb
Public Sub CountColorCells()
    
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, i As Long, arrClrs, m, ws As Worksheet
    
    arrClrs = Array(RGB(146, 208, 80), RGB(255, 255, 0), RGB(255, 0, 0), RGB(0, 176, 240))
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("statut projet et Gate")
    ws.Range("M1:M4").Value = 0 'reset counts
    Set rng = ws.Range("M8:M1000")
    For i = 1 To 7
        For Each c In rng.Cells
            'match color against array
            m = Application.Match(c.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color, arrClrs, 0)
            If Not IsError(m) Then
                'not an error, so got a match on color
                ws.Range("M1").Offset(m, 0) = ws.Range("M1").Offset(m, 0) + 1
            End If
        Next c
        Set rng = rng.Offset(0, 4) 'next range is 4 columns to right
    Next i
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you William, I am testing this, but for the loop for..Next, where is the variable i ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  It's right there in the `For` and `Next`.  It's not used inside the loop because it's not needed there: it's just a counter.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, your help  was inspiring: Finaly I get the solution  that works: here is the VBA code:

> Blockquote

```
Public Sub CountColorCells()
'Variable declaration
Dim rng As Range
     
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim arrClrs(1 To 4) As Variant

arrClrs(1) = RGB(146, 208, 80)
arrClrs(2) = RGB(255, 255, 0)
arrClrs(3) = RGB(255, 0, 0)
arrClrs(4) = RGB(0, 176, 240)

'Set the range
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("statut projet et Gate")
ws.Range("M2:M5,Q2:Q5,U2:U5,Y2:Y5,AC2:AC5,AG2:AG5,AK2:AK5").Value = 0
Set rng = ws.Range("M8:M1000")
```

For j = 1 To 7

```
'loop throught each cell in the range
```

For Each rngCell In rng.Offset(0, (j - 1) * 4)
For i = 1 To 4

```
  If Cells(rngCell.Row, rngCell.Column).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = arrClrs(i) Then
         
    ws.Range("M2").Offset(i - 1, (j - 1) * 4) = ws.Range("M2").Offset(i - 1, (j - 1) * 4) + 1
                        
  End If
```

Next i

Next

Next j

End Sub

> Blockquote